# How can I ask emacs to show me (visually) invisible characters like CR LF?

Tags: whitespace, characters

The title says it all:  I want emacs to show (all, or only some, like CR LF) invisible characters in my buffer? (If it matters: I am using the latest emacs (25) on the latest debian testing)

(I am not used to the tags used on this site, so please help to make more useful tags)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out <kbd>M-x</kbd>`whitespace-mode` and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd>`whitespace`

By default it is set up to visually emphasise spaces, tabs, and line endings, but you can tune it to eg leave spaces alone.